# PPTP VPN works from office but not from home on same laptop

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I want to access an Oracle database from Python's cx_Oracle module using my laptop (Windows XP SP3). The DB is hosted on a remote server configured by a third party. They set up a PPTP VPN for doing so.

Now when I bring my laptop to my office, **everything works fine**.

However, when I take the exact same steps on the same laptop at home, something goes wrong and I'm not sure what. The **symptoms** are

- I can usually connect flawlessly to the VPN (or so it seems anyway)
- My entire internet connection seems slow when VPN connected
- Pinging the DB host usually (but not always) times out
- When using `tracert` on the DB host, the first steps are OK, later ones tend to time out
- DB requests tend to time out
- I succeeded only once (out of some 25 attempts) to actually access the DB

I suspect the problem is in my **home router** (Zyxel p-2812hnu-f1) but I'm not very familiar with networking and I don't know what may be likely causes - let alone how to fix it.

"VPN" is mentioned only once in its entire [manual](ftp://ftp.zyxel.nl/P-2812HNU-F3/P-2812HNU-F3_1.0.pdf) so that doesn't really help either.

Any suggestions are more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your router indeed does not seem to have any provision for **VPN passthrough**, which should be enabled to allow you to connect to a remote server. There is no mention of PPTP, nor VPN, nor passthrough in the index of its [User's Guide](ftp://ftp2.zyxel.com/P-2812HNU-F1/user_guide/P-2812HNU-F1_1.00.pdf). It really looks like you will have to get a different model, to allow you to connect to *any* VPN.

Comment: I **did** access the DB (once) via my router over VPN so I do believe the router is capable of doing it.